# Ajax vs Images loading priority

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, jquery

I have the following scenario:

I have about 50 ajax request (all sent in a javascript loop) which have to populate a table with article information. Those articles also include images.

My problem:

When I place the answers (a table row) from the ajax request in the table, it will not load the images intermediately. It will wait until all request have been received and it will then start to load the images.

Is there a way to allow the images to load first? Or at least after each ajax request. I mean it's not a synchronous request and even then it shouldn't block image transfer as far as i know...

Comment: "I have about 50 ajax request (all sent in a javascript loop)"  bad idea! Can't you do it using only one ajax request?

Comment: We had that before...the problem is that loading an article from the ERP needs about 100ms each which results in 5-6 seconds for loading the data. This is to long...so we decided to load each article individually so the user can already interact with the data before it is fully loaded.

Comment: You could load the first one individually, then begin to load the next one when the user gets close to scrolling it into view, etc. aka infinite scroll.

Comment: We will use 10 article paging for now, so only 10 request...but the problem is still the same...the images load after the ajax requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to encode images in base64 to get what you want. But this will include some overhead.

Also... what roasted said.